How to use ViewBindings for mutiple layouts
I'm migrating from kotlinx.android.synthetic to ViewBindings.
I have two layouts(for phones and tablets) with the same set of ids:
class GameActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ViewBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (AppData.instance.isTablet)
            binding=ActivityGameTabletBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        else
            binding=ActivityGamePhoneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val btn=binding.menuBtn //no such property
    }
    ...

}

The problem is binding contains only one property which is root.
Thus I'm forced to fallback to old getViewById. Is there way to have viewBinding features for different layouts?

What I would suggest is set each view variable in the respective if/else blocks (assuming they both have the same stuff in the layouts just arranged differently), then reference the views variables that you just set like normal

ViewBinding really doesn't support anything like "sharing" the views. You either need to get creative with your layout to fit it in one binding (for example if you use ConstraintLayout you can have one set of views and apply different constraint sets) or create an ugly workaround like delegate for your viewbindings that can wrap either of them (a bit of copy pasting job there and it's headache to maintain if you're still developing the layouts).

You can try ViewStub or interface.

You cannot have a variable have binded to 2 different views instead you can create 2 variables and initialize both of them and use them accordingly.
Here is an example.
private lateinit var phoneBinding : ActivityGamePhoneBinding
private lateinit var tabletBinding : ActivityGameTabletBinding

Then initialize both of them.
phoneBinding = ActivityGamePhoneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
tabletBinding = ActivityGameTabletBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

  if (AppData.instance.isTablet){
       val btn = tabletBinding.button
       //Do rest of your tablet code
  } else {
       val btn = phoneBinding.button
       //Do rest of your phone code
  }

If you are doing common things you should create a function and call the same function in both scenarios.
phoneBinding = ActivityGamePhoneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
tabletBinding = ActivityGameTabletBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

  if (AppData.instance.isTablet){
       val btn = tabletBinding.button
       onButtonClick(btn)
  } else {
       val btn = phoneBinding.button
       onButtonClick(btn)
  }

  fun onButtonClick(button : Button){
   button.setOnclickListner{
    //rest of you code.
   }
  }


Yes I came up with the same solution. See answer below

good job..its good to find solution of the problem on your own

For those who might facing the same problem. I found two solutions:
Method 1:
Use kotlin-reflection library to get properties by it's string name:
private inline fun <T>getViewByName(name:String):T{
        val prop= binding::class.memberProperties.find { it.name==name }
        val view=prop?.call(binding) as T
        if (view!=null) {
            return view
        } else
            throw Exception("view not found")
    }

I find this method quite hacky, so I sticked to the second one:
class GameActivityBinding(private val binding:ViewBinding) {
  val menuBtn:ImageButton
        get() {
            return when (binding) {
                is ActivityGameTabletBinding -> {
                    binding.menuBtn
                }

                is ActivityGamePhoneBinding -> {
                    binding.menuBtn
                }
                else -> throw Exception("incorrect layout")
            }
        }
    // rest of the views
}

No need to litter code with dozens of if-else's
